# String contains any entry from array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspredicate

I would like to determine does string contains any element of array using `NSPredicate`. For example, suppose next string exist:
`NSString *component = @"appleMouse";` 
I would like to determine, does `component` string contains any of following array entry: `NSArray *components = @[@"logitec", @"apple"]`. In pseudo predicate format string this will looks like: "`component CONTAINS[c] ANY $Components`", but in real predicate format string this string produce error: "Unable to parse the format string".

Expected Results:
`BOOL contains = [predicate evaluateWithObject:component]; // YES`

Maybe someone solves similar problem and know how? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if this works with a NSPredicate.

If you want to do an exact match, you can reverse your logic and use `containsObject:` like this:

`BOOL contains = [components containsObject:component];`

Or, if you need more sophisticated tests (like substring etc.), use `indexOfObjectPassingTest:`:

`NSUInteger foundAtIndex = [components indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([component rangeOfString:obj] != {NSNotFound, 0}) {
                return YES;
            }
            return NO;
        }];`

(didn't test the code, from memory)

Comment: The first suggestion is too strict for @Lexandr's purposes, but the second should work. I altered it a little to get it to compile and test it: `const NSUInteger foundAtIndex = [components indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) { if (!NSEqualRanges([component rangeOfString:obj], NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) { return YES; } return NO; }]; const BOOL contains = foundAtIndex != NSNotFound;`